# Melhor forma de desenvolver um grid com flexbox?

Tags: html, css, css3, aplicação-web, grid

Eu tenho duvidas com o `display:flex`, pensando em um sistema de grid como seria o `container`, `row` e a `column`.

Por exemplo o container teria a propriedade `display:flex`? E como organizar a `row` e a `column`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lennon, comecei a usar mais o `display:flex` no css como um meio de substituir o `float`, o que ajudou muito a usabilidade da própria pagina.

Bem primeiro vamos entender como funciona o `display flex`, ele oi feito com o proposito de conseguir deixar qualquer `div` se posicionar em qualquer direção e poder ter dimensões flexíveis para se adaptar.

```
<div style="display:flex;height: 100px;width: 400px;">
     <div style="background:#FFFF00;width: 150px;"></div>
     <div style="background:#FF00FF;width: 150px;"></div>
     <div style="background:#FFFF00;width: 150px;"></div>
     <div style="background:#FF00FF;width: 150px;"></div>
</div>
```

A orientação de como os elementos de dentro da `div` que tem o `display flex` se da por outros atributos do css, no caso de orientação horizontal e vertical se da pelo `flex-wrap:wrap` onde você muda a direção para vertical

```
<div style="display:flex;height: 100px;width: 400px;flex-wrap:wrap;">
     <div style="background:#FF00FF;width: 150px;"></div>
     <div style="background:#FFFF00;width: 150px;"></div>
     <div style="background:#FFFF00;width: 150px;"></div>
     <div style="background:#FF00FF;width: 150px;"></div>
</div>
```

Bem para um começo acho que já da para entender, segue um artigo do *tableless* de como funciona `displays` em flex http://tableless.com.br/flexbox-organizando-seu-layout/ .

Espero ter ajudado e lembre-se que `flex` ainda não é um atributo aceito em todos os browsers então precisa usar prefixos como `-webkit-`, `-moz-`, `-ms-`, `-o-`.

Comment: Opa bacana me ajudou